# Angular 2 - Populate JSON array to the view only after x seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I generate a JSON array (manually and based on random numbers) on the `controller` level. However, I want to show the elements of that JSON array after 15 seconds, on that 15 seconds `on the view` I want to display `pending status` then after the 15 seconds `pending` will be replaced by the results of the JSON array.

Any idea on how can I do that?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` and set some flags?

Comment: `Observable.of(data).delay(15000).subscribe(...)`?

Comment: I did, but the issue is that on the `view` I have an `*ngFor`, when it does not find an array to go through, it throws an error

Comment: @Folky.H then start with a default empty array, or guard it with `ngIf`/`ngSwitch`. If you've tried something that didn't work, *give a [mcve]*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe does it works even if the data was generated locally. Also, I have an *ngFor that goes through the array, I believe that it will through an error, am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that's what `Observable.of` is for, creating an observable of data you already have. The advantage is that you can easily switch this out for a network fetch without much refactoring. And without more information nobody can tell you whether it will *throw* an error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll try out your suggestion and get back, thanks anyway !

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with @jonrsharpe's comment,

```
/* component */
this.later = Observable.of(data).delay(15000);

<!-- template -->
<div *ngIf="later | async as data; else wait">{{data}}</div>
<div #wait>Wait...</div>
```

This will require Angular 4.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion !